# Displaying multiple regions shapefiles on iOS device?

Tags: shapefile, ios

How can I display multiple shapefiles on an iOS device?

My client is asking to display all the states in a different color, and again cities in a different color and all the fields in a different color with lat/longs.

I was not able to proceed further with such a huge requirement so how should I start?

What are the requirements for moving forward?

Are there any GiS specialists needed for me to know completely about the shapefiles?

Comment: see - shape to json  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223979/convert-a-shapefile-shp-to-xml-json

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a WMS server at your server which would deliver pre rendered tiles to your device. One option you have is to use free and opensource server from geoserver.org. you can use different styles with rules on the server and can import the shapefile(or many other geo data formats). There are many options available at client side for consuming the tiles from WMS and display on the device/page/application. This would help you to become completely transparent about different geo data formats.

Regards
Sudheesh

Answer (score 1):

You could import the shapefiles into a web map and render the states and cities with a unique or class break renderer with the use of [ArcGIS SDK](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-ios-sdk/concepts/00pw/00pw00000003000000.htm) if it is just for viewing.  Editing attributes would require setting up a feature service.  The ArcGIS SDK supports both of these options.